# Unable to See Run button under the @Test annotation in maven selenium project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have recently installed selenium webdriver using Maven and TestNg. I added all the dependencies in the pom.xml but don’t know why I don’t see the run button under the @test annotation in my test class due to which I am unable to run my test.

Please if someone can help with this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUhz.jpg)

Comment: Use IntelliJ IDEA, it's much better than Eclipse and comes with installed plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-importing the Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA and rebuild it

Comment: Thanks for responding but any idea why it did not work in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Install TestNG plugin in eclipse https://testng.org/doc/download.html
and after install, add testNG library to project, then try